# How to get Google Calendar API refresh token as a string to store in the database using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, api, google-calendar-api

```
using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
        System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");


    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
```

This code writes the tokens to a file.
I need to get the Refresh token in string format in order to save it in the database for a particular user. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `IDataStore` yourself? (That's the type of the last parameter to `AuthorizeAsync`.)

Comment: I think this [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/) can help you to Authenticate the Google Calendar API with C#. It also shows example code here that you can follow. For more information, check these related SO question [26098009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098009) and [29776725](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776725). Also, another tutorial that can help you is this [Google OAuth2 for C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/#Stored_refresh-Token).

Answer (score -1):

This is the good info using:

```
var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");

    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
    (
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
    ).Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
```